# Is it okay to use the same Subscriptions table for multiple publishers?

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I have multiple publishers which want to persist their subscription info in storage.  Is it okay for them to use the same table in the same database, or do I need to separate them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can multiple NServiceBus publishers share the same DBSubscriptionStorage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626155/can-multiple-nservicebus-publishers-share-the-same-dbsubscriptionstorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
In one of our huge projects at work we have a setup like you describe it and it works like charm.

We have several windows services communicating with each other. All services use the same table in the same database to manage their subscriptions without any conflicts..